# The initialization of the Trusted Platform Module (TPM) failed

Tags: windows-10, tpm

Today I've checked EventViewer -> Windows Logs -> System and saw that almost every second there is error entry with a message

> The initialization of the Trusted Platform Module (TPM) failed. The
>   TPM may be in failure mode. To allow diagnosis, contact the TPM
>   manufacturer with the attached information.

can't open `tpm.msc` console, it says

[image]

Command `get-tpm` in PowerShell returns:

```
get-tpm : The TPM returned an unexpected result. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8029010C)
At line:1 char:1
+ get-tpm
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-Tpm], TpmWmiException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Tpm.Commands.TpmWmiException,Microsoft.Tpm.Commands.GetTpmCommand
```

I booted to safe mode, everything seems to work fine (console works, power shell command works, no event log errors).

Comment: Device Manager, Security Devices, Trusted Platform Module:  What does Device Manager say about this Device.  Get the TPM Software from your computer manufacturer and upgrade or reinstall it. Then restart and check.

Comment: @John Device manager says "This device is working properly."

Comment: Try reinstalling it from the manufacturer's support site for downloading drivers.  Also, since TPM can be tied to BIOS, update BIOS and Chipset if there is a Chipset driver

Comment: @John Can it have other names, because I'm unable to find anything related to TPM in the drivers section of my device. Sorry I don't fully know what is TPM for, just noticed errors and want to fix it.

Comment: For my machine, it shows up in the support drivers web page as:  TPM Firmware Update Utility.

Comment: @John ok thanks, didn't find it, but found an upgrade package, will try to upgrade.